# Does anyone know the names for each relative in mandarin?

Tags: characters

I know in mandarin each relative has a specific name. I tried searching it up, but I can't find anything. Can someone provide me the resources, please?

Comment: In the old days, especially among farming communities, it was not uncommon for 3 -- 4 generations of an extended family living under one roof and thus the need to address each and every member correctly on a daily basis, not by name but by status, and addressing someone's status incorrectly, especially someone older was almost a sin, at least considered ill-mannered. It may seem complicated, but it comes naturally as one is taught as soon as one could speak.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how could you search for this without finding anything? Typing in "mandarin relatives names" in a search engine gives me a long list of pages that answers this specific question.

Comment: They used Bing?

Comment: There are also some mobile apps called relative calculation you can check.

Answer (score 2):

This may help:  [親屬稱謂](https://www.hao-net.com/ikebukuroblog/2019/02/18/%E2%98%85%E8%B1%86%E7%9F%A5%E8%AD%98%E2%98%85%E2%80%95%E5%8F%B0%E6%B9%BE%E3%81%AE%E8%A6%AA%E6%97%8F%E3%81%AE%E5%91%BC%E3%81%B3%E6%96%B9/)

[image]

Notice:

爺爺 = 祖父

奶奶 = 祖母

外公 = 外祖父

外婆 = 外祖母

伯伯 = 伯父

叔叔 = 叔父

姑姑 = 姑母

嬸嬸 = 叔母

舅舅 = 舅父

舅媽 = 舅母

爸爸 = 父親

媽媽 = 母親

阿姨 = 姨母

堂哥 = 堂兄

表兄弟姊妹 from 姑姑's side are 姑表

表兄弟姊妹 from 姨母's side are 姨表

Husband and wife are 丈夫 and 妻子 (also:老公 and 老婆)

Great grandfather and Great grandmother are 曾祖父 and 曾祖母; 外曾祖父 and 外曾祖母

your 妻子's 哥哥 is your 大舅

your 妻子's 弟弟 is your 小舅

your 妻子's 姊姊 is your 大姨

your 妻子's 妹妹 is your 小姨

Your 丈夫's 哥哥 is your 大伯

Your 丈夫's 弟弟 is your 小叔

Your 丈夫's 姊姊 is your 大姑

Your 丈夫's 妹妹 is your 小姑

Comment: And if your father has more than one wife?

Comment: If your mother is the first wife, the second wife would be your 二媽; If your mother is the second wife, the first wife would be your 大媽. You always call your own mother 媽媽

Comment: A slight difference in my family. Maybe because we are Hakkas. I don't know. If I am a child of the first wife, I call the second wife  細婶. Beyond the second wife, I have no idea.

Comment: If your father only has two wives, you can call the second wife 細媽 instead of 二媽. If your father has five wives, and your mother is the first wife, the other wives would be your 二媽，三媽，四媽，五媽 (細媽)

Comment: How can the sons and daughters of 姨丈、阿姨 be your 堂兄弟姐妹？They are your 表兄弟姐妹。堂 stands for 祖宗祠堂，people who belong to the same 祖宗祠堂 have the same family name, same bloodline.

Comment: Seems like the table made a mistake, I edited it

Comment: is polygamy still a thing?

Comment: Not for modern Chinese people.  Two generations before maybe. My father was the 19th son of my grandfather (the elder of three brothers from the same mother). I am sure he had more than three or four  wives

Comment: BTW, it has been a cultural edict that persons of the same surname are not allowed to marry each other, even if from two different families who have no apparent family ties. Because it was assumed that people of the same surname were at some time in the distant past shared the same ancestor, and thus are of the same family, like distant brothers and sisters. So, inbreeding is avoided. And further people whose surnames "clash", (meaning having a negative connotation when combined), are encouraged not to marry, like 谢 & 葉, which could mean "withering leaves"

Comment: @Wayne Cheah Not China today, The world have advanced, people are more open-minded even same surname marriage is no longer taboo

Comment: @Tang Ho. I have yet to meet a Chinese husband and wife with the same surname in all of my 71 years. Have you? Perhaps those from China itself can share their experiences?

Comment: @Wayne Cheah I worked in Chinese restaurants from 18- 27, I have seen hundreds of wedding and I do recall a few couples had the same family name. Because there are so many people who have the big five names 陳李張黃何. there is more chance for 陳陳聯婚 than 白刀聯婚 or 叢林聯婚 (There might be many funny ones: for example ： 瀨史聯婚， 崔肅聯婚， 烏歸聯婚， 朱楊聯婚...

Comment: 如果姓張的不能跟姓張的結婚，那真不知會㧪殺多少良緣. From https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%90%8C%E5%A7%93%E4%B8%8D%E5%A9%9A ..... 宋亦依唐律，同姓为婚干杖而离之。明、清后逐渐消亡。

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for sharing your "work experience"